# How do I set keyboard repeat rate automatically for a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

How do I set keyboard repeat rate automatically for a bluetooth keyboard if the bluetooth keyboard is connected after the computer has already started?

On X startup, I have an `.xinitrc` that does `xset` for me, but the bluetooth keyboard is connected after X starts.

I also have `Option "AutoRepeat"` set up in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`, and I see these appear in X logs at `.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`,

```
[    36.452] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Keychron K8 Pro Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
[    36.452] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    36.452] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    36.452] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[    36.453] (**) Option "AutoRepeat" "200 200"
[    36.453] (**) AutoRepeat: 200 200
```

but the repeat rate is still much slower than when I manually execute `xset r rate 200 200`

Answer (score 1):

I've created https://github.com/SFTtech/xautocfg to solve this problem - it can automatically apply the desired repeat rate to newly connected keyboards.

Normaly your desktop environment should handle the keyboard config, but I suppose yours doesn't have this feature.